# Cannot call value of non-function type'((Selector)->Bool)!

Tags: ios, swift

I got a compile error called "Cannot call value of non-function type'((Selector)->Bool)!'", The following is part of my codes:

`public protocol DictModelProtocol {
         func customerClassMapping() -> [String:String]
}`

```
func test(cls:AnyClass) -> [String:String] {
    var customerMapping:[String:String]
    if cls.respondsToSelector(#selector(DictModelProtocol.customerClassMapping)) {
        customerMapping = cls.customerClassMapping()
    }
    return customerMapping}
```

Comment: I think you may also have a problem with returning an uninitialized value; what happens if you don't enter the `if` block?

Comment: Why are you using `respondsToSelector`? Have you tried using the `if let` syntax?

Comment: Also, it's possible that this function would work better as a generic `func test<T: DictModeProtocol>(cls: T) -> [String:String]` and then you don't need the `respondsToSelector`